# Why did Ubuntu 22.04 decide to uninstall Sayonara music player and VLC?

Tags: updates, 22.04, music-player

Ubuntu just did some updates which required restart. There were both 'snap'-updates and ordinary updates and Lenovo firmware updates.
After that I tried to start Sayonara (music player), but nothing started. I pressed the 'Windows'-key on my keyboard and typed 'software', thereby opening the standard Ubuntu software repository. It showed Sayonara as not installed, so I pressed the install button. But now it no longer works in a way I find logical. Instead of showing a list of sound files and subdirectories it says "Unkown artist 482"... So in practice Ubuntu has made it much more complicated for me to play my music files.

PS: When pressing the 'Windows'-key and typing 'sayonara' I see 2 'Sayonara'...

PPS: Ubuntu also destroyed my VLC player and possibly more!?

Edit: I try to explain more precisely what happened.

Comment: Can you elaborate "now it no longer works in a way I find logical"?

Comment: Instead of showing a list of sound files and subdirectories it says "Unkown artist 482"...

Comment: I just discovered that Ubuntu also deleted my VLC... I am a bit shocked!!

Comment: Please [edit] the question and explain how you installed the played and what is the problem. Also please remove rant about why Ubuntu did that, etc.

Comment: Ubuntu did not delete them something else is going on.

Comment: I'm confused by what "*some updates*" means: apt upgrade? apt full-upgrade? apt dist-upgrade? unattended upgrade? do-release-upgrade? update-manager upgrade? snap refresh? Something else? A question that includes more accurate facts and real input and output --and avoids vagueness-- is much likelier to get helpful answers.

Comment: I guess that it was a regular GUI update. But something is wrong anyway.

Comment: Removed "bug-reporting" tag. This is not a question about how to report a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I used my old standard "MS-Windows solution"... ;-)

In other words: I restored a 2 months old drive image backup of the Ubuntu partition, which I had created with Paragon HD Manager 16 Basic.
Now Sayonara and VLC work again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your library path and file system matches? If everything seems ok, a library reload might fix your issue. Menubar -> Library -> Reload Library.

If not, please open a bug + screenshot in https://gitlab.com/luciocarreras/sayonara-player/-/issues .

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just restored a drive image of the Ubuntu partition, so it's too late to test it. :-) But your suggestion doesn't explain why VLC and other software also stopped working.